# Derivative of characteristic polynomial of a graph and derivative of characteristic polynomial of a vertex-deleted subgraph have a common root

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, spectral-graph-theory, differential-calculus

Let $G$ be a simple graph and $G-i$ be one of its vertex-deleted subgraphs. Let $\phi(G,x)$ and $\phi(G-i,x)$ be the characteristic polynomials of $G$ and of $G-i$ respectively, with respect to their 0-1 adjacency matrices.

Suppose $\phi^\prime(G,x)$ and $\phi^\prime(G-i,x)$ have a common root $\lambda$. ($f^\prime(x)$ is the derivative of $f(x)$ with respect to $x$.) Does it follow that $\lambda$ is also a root of $\phi(G,x)$? In other words, must $\lambda$ be a multiple eigenvalue of $G$?